# How to set height constraint of UITableView according to dynamic height cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have `TableView` and I set an initial constraint to it as 10.0, for example. Now, I've added 3 cells with the different height sizes(they are autolayout cells), for example, they sizes are `(50.0, 120.0, 30.0)`

How can I set now my `UITableView.heightConstraint = 50 + 120 + 30?`

How can I take autolayout cell size? When I try to print their size I get initial size(standard 44.0)

Any ideas?

Comment: try to get cell size from viewDidAppear !

Comment: @sam uitableview ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded() 
self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: Great! It works, but at first I need to scroll down and back to top for updating the size. Can I solve this too?

Comment: Didn't get your question.

Comment: You should put this in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: what is that `tableViewHeightConstraint`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate tableviewcell height dynamically..
Try this...

```
CGfloat height= [self.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height+2;
```